# Excel: How to lock a cell based on another cell in the same row

Tags: c#, excel, devexpress, spreadsheet

I am working on export excel sheet using Devexpress library- Spreadsheet in c#.

I have 2 columns, 1st column with a dropdown (True/False) and 2nd column is just a text field.
If row has 1st column selected as True then it should lock the 2nd column and not allow to enter any values in it.

Was trying this (https://docs.devexpress.com/WPF/DevExpress.Xpf.Spreadsheet.SpreadsheetControl.CellValueChanged) event to catch and do my logic but didn't had any luck.

Need help..

Answer (score 0):

You can use `CellBeginEdit` event

```
void spreadsheetControl1_CellBeginEdit(object sender, SpreadsheetCellCancelEventArgs e) {
    if (e.ColumnIndex == 1) {
        var cellValue = e.Worksheet[e.RowIndex, 0].Value;
        e.Cancel = cellValue.IsBoolean && cellValue.BooleanValue;
    }
}
```